# How to call a function that returns an array by implementing composability

Tags: solidity, remix

I have two solidity files named `SimpleStorage` and `StorageFactory`. `SimpleStorage` file contains the functions that store and retrieve the users' name and age. The other solidity file `StorageFactory` deploys the contract and extract the functions.

SimpleStorage.sol

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity 0.8.8;

contract SimpleStorage{

    struct People{
        string name;
        uint256 age;
    }

    People[] person;

    function setPerson(string memory _name, uint256 _age) public{
        People memory newPerson = People({name:_name, age:_age});
        person.push(newPerson);
    }

    function getPerson() public view returns (People[] memory){
        return person;
    }
}
```

StorageFactory.sol

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity 0.8.8;

import "./SimpleStorage.sol";

contract StorageFactory{

SimpleStorage[] simpleStorageArray;

 struct People{
     string name;
     uint256 age;
 }

 People[] people;

function createSimpleStorageContract() public {
    SimpleStorage simpleStorage = new SimpleStorage();
    simpleStorageArray.push(simpleStorage);
}

function sfSetPerson(uint256 contractAddressIndex, string memory _name, uint256 _age) public {
    SimpleStorage simpleStorage = simpleStorageArray[contractAddressIndex];
    simpleStorage.setPerson(_name, _age);
}

function sfGetPerson(uint256 contractAddressIndex) public view returns (People[] memory){
    SimpleStorage  simpleStorage = simpleStorageArray[contractAddressIndex];
    return simpleStorage.getPerson();
}

}
```

I want to call the function `getPerson` which returns an array from the `StorageFactory.sol` but getting the error:

`from solidity: TypeError: Return argument type struct SimpleStorage.People memory[] memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type (type of first return variable) struct StorageFactory.People memory[] memory. --> contracts/StorageFactory.sol:30:12: | 30 |     return simpleStorage.getPerson();`

Answer (score 0):

This error happen because you declared two structs with the same name, in this case: Person.
Thus, in `sfGetPerson()` method you must declare inside `returns` keyword the contract name and its relative struct name.
You must change this function in this way:

```
function sfGetPerson(uint256 contractAddressIndex) public view returns (SimpleStorage.People[] memory){
        SimpleStorage simpleStorage = simpleStorageArray[contractAddressIndex];
        return simpleStorage.getPerson();
}
```

In the following lines, I put your `StorageFactory` smart contract modified:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.8;

import "./SimpleStorage.sol";

contract StorageFactory{
    SimpleStorage[] simpleStorageArray;

    struct People{
        string name;
        uint256 age;
    }

    People[] people;

    function createSimpleStorageContract() public {
        SimpleStorage simpleStorage = new SimpleStorage();
        simpleStorageArray.push(simpleStorage);
    }

    function sfSetPerson(uint256 contractAddressIndex, string memory _name, uint256 _age) public {
        SimpleStorage simpleStorage = simpleStorageArray[contractAddressIndex];
        simpleStorage.setPerson(_name, _age);
    }

    function sfGetPerson(uint256 contractAddressIndex) public view returns (SimpleStorage.People[] memory){
        SimpleStorage simpleStorage = simpleStorageArray[contractAddressIndex];
        return simpleStorage.getPerson();
    }

}
```